# How to make a map with predetermined strings as key?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I want to define a map with predetermined strings in JSDoc. Such as:

```
/**
 * @typedef {'date' | 'string' | 'integer' | 'float' | 'currency' | 'description'} ColumnTypes
 * @type {Map<ColumnTypes, string>}
 */
typeMap = {
    'string': 'varchar(max)',
    'integer': 'decimal(18,4)',
    'date': 'smalldatetime',
}
```

I tried to write it like that, but I didn't see the options list for the keys like when I use `@type {ColumnTypes}`

A typescript equivalent would be:

```
type ColumnTypes = ('datetime' | 'string' | 'integer' | 'decimal' | 'currency' | 'text')
type DatamapType = {
    [key in ColumnTypes]: string;
}
```

But I don't know how to write that in jsdoc.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following would do it:

```js
/**
 * @typedef {'date' | 'string' | 'integer' | 'float' | 'currency' | 'description'} ColumnTypes
 * @type {Record<ColumnTypes, string>}
 */
const typeMap = {
  'string': 'varchar(max)',
  'integer': 'decimal(18,4)',
  'date': 'smalldatetime',
  'float': 'float',
  'currency': 'currency',
  'description': 'description',
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is a little off. You can write it like this.
You can learn about jsdoc from [here](https://jsdoc.app/tags-type.html#syntax).

```
/**
  * @typedef {(string | number | Date )} ColumnTypes
  * @type {Map.<ColumnTypes, string>}
 */
 typeMap = {
  'string': 'varchar(max)',
  'integer': 'decimal(18,4)',
  'date': 'smalldatetime',
}
```

Comment: No... It is a string, not a datatype in javascript. It is a mapper for my report application's data type not javascript's data type.